# Is there a way to efficiently synchronize a subset of theads using OpenMP?

Tags: openmp

Because OpenMP nested parallelism has often performance problems, I was wondering if there is a way to implement a *partial* barrier that would synchronize only a subset of all threads.
Here is an example code structure:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int nth = omp_get_num_threads();
    int tid = omp_get_thread_num();

    if (tid < nth/2) {
        // do some work
        ...
        // I need some synchronization here, but only for nth/2 threads
        #pragma omp partial_barrier(nth/2)
        // do some more work
        ...
    } else {
       // do some other independent work
       ...
    }
}
```

I did not find anything like that in the openmp standard, but maybe there is a way to efficiently program a similar behaviour with locks or something?

**EDIT:**
So my actual problem is that I have a computation kernel (a Legendre transform -- part **A**) that is efficiently parallelized using OpenMP with 4 to 12 threads depending on the problem size.
This computation is followed by a Fast Fourier transform (part **B**).
I have several independent datasets (typically about 6 to 10) that have to be processed by A followed by B.
I would like to use more parallelism with more threads (48 to 128, depending on the machines).
Since A is not efficiently parallelized with more than 4 to 12 threads, the idea is to split the threads into several groups, each group working on an independent dataset. Because the datasets are independent, I don't need to synchronize all the threads (which is quite expensive when many threads are used) before doing B, only the subset working on a given dataset.

OpenMP tasks with depenencies would do what I need, but my experience is that on some platforms (xeon servers) the performance is significantly lower to what you can get with simple threads.

Is there a way to synchronize a subset of threads efficiently?

Comment: It would be interesting to know a bit more about what you are really trying to do.  OpenMP doesn't really *do* barriers and synchronisation, though it provides some tools for implementing them.  As your question stands it is rather like *I have devised a solution to a problem (which I do not explain) how may I perfect the solution ?* You might get better answers if you explain the problem more clearly

Comment: As Mark says, please explain your actual problem. It's certainly possible that using tasks may be a better approach...

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have added the description of the actual problem at the end of the question.

Comment: As @JimCownie said, it is probably a good idea to use tasks here. Also note that OpenMP 5.0 added `taskwait` directive with a `depend` close to wait for specific tasks.
`on some platforms (xeon servers) the performance is significantly lower to what you can get with simple threads` The OpenMP runtime used should also have a strong impact.

Comment: As @JérômeRichard says, as soon as you start talking about performance you need also to say which compiler you are using, and, if it's not the default, which runtime. (For codes that do not use "omp target" it is generally possible to use the LLVM/Intel runtime with GCC compiled code, which can make a significant difference to performance). If you want to point out a performance issue in an OpenMP runtime and get it fixed, the right people need to know about it, and at the moment it's impossible for anyone to know who those people are!

Comment: p.s. If you really have completely independent datasets, then simply running independent jobs seems the easiest approach!